# keep jqueryui overlay in same DOM position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, overlay, modal-dialog

Is there anyway to keep a `jQueryUI` overlay in the same DOM position?

### [Take a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/HjhRD/)

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="over" title="title">
        Stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#over').dialog({modal: true});
```

If you inspect it on the DOM, you'll notice that the overlay gets moved to a direct child of `document.body`

Is there any way to keep it in it's starting position? (direct child of `div#parent`)?

Comment: When you put it as modal then it can only be a child of body, because it overlays all other children of body.

Comment: @SvenBieder: And if I wouldn't have it as a modal?

Comment: Then it should normally stay in the original position. But I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want this, but something like: http://jsfiddle.net/BGBuc/ should get you started.

JS

```
$('#over').dialog({
    modal: true,
    create:function(event, ui) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#parent').append($('div.ui-widget-overlay')).append($('div.ui-dialog'));
        },1);
    }
});​
```